# Merge lines which don't match a regex

Tags: regex, file, awk, sed, http-accept-language

I have a file which contains logs from the web; a simplified version of it is as follows:

```
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
Unix
Linux
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
START
Solaris
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
Aix
SCO
```

I have tried a couple of Regex combinations to identify the Accept-Language which is the beginning of every line using the following with awk/sed:

```
/^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/
/\*|[A-Z]{1,8}(-[A-Z0-9]{1,8})*/i  
/([^-;]*)(?:-([^;]*))?(?:;q=([0-9]\.[0-9]))?/
```

So far I haven't managed to get either awk/sed to give me the following results:

```
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;    Unix    Linux
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;    STAR    Solaris
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;    Aix    SCO
```

Any help is appreciated. The file contains about 1 Million+ records so I'm happy to go down a route that doesn't use sed/awk and improves performance.

Comment: In your desired output, I believe you have an extra line. Remove one of the first three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}/ { print b; b=$0; next }  # @xx-XX empty buffer, refill
                           { b=b OFS $0 }           # otherwise append to buffer
                       END { print b }' file        # dump the buffer in the end

en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd;
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd; Unix Linux
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd; START Solaris
en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en    jsdjpksdkskd;lkskd; Aix SCO
```

You will get an empty line to start the output with. Also, use tab delimiter on output if so desired: `awk -v OFS="\t" ...`.

Comment: This script has not worked for me it takes all the lines into one.

Comment: @AmineJaidi That's  odd. What's your environment and which awk do you use?

Comment: I'm on Redhat not using GAWK. The things is the file is already \t delimited to basically the problem I am trying to solve here is make sure that all lines that are not starting with a regex Accept-language one to be appended to the previous one. The sed solution below is working it would be good to know how AWK can do it I've had a stab with no luck. I have implemented the SED solution as part of a reduce function in Hadoop and it is quite slow

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that your awk doesn't support `{2}` in regex. Replace regex: `/[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}` with `/[a-z][a-z]-[A-Z][A-Z]`.

Comment: That was spot on now the script works now but it adds a \n at the beginning of the file :(

Comment: I know, I mentioned that in my solution. Gimme a second to see if it's an easy one.

Comment: Adding `if(b!="")` before the `print b; ...` in the first line should fix the problem (or `if(NR>1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the observation, that we can distinguish the two types of lines on the `=`, you can use this awk script:

**file.awk**

```
$0 ~ /=/ { printf("%s%s", v,$0)
           v="\n"
           next
         } 
         { printf("\t%s", $0) } 
END      { printf("\n") }
```

You use it like this: `awk -f file.awk yourfile`

- `v` is empty for the first line, later it contains the linebreak
- for lines with an `=`, we print `$0` preceded by `v`
- for the other lines (note the `next` in the first action), we print `$0` without the newline but with a `\t` as separation

Comment: Don't hard-code the newline string with `printf("\n")`, use `print ""` instead so awk can use whatever newline string is appropriate for the environment it's being called from, e.g. `\r\n`. Also, you don't need the `$0 ~` as that's the default.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a sed solution:

```
sed -ne 1bgo \
   -e '/^[a-z][a-z]-[A-Z][A-Z]/ { x;p;s/.*//;x; };:go' \
   -e 'H;x;s/^\n//;s/\n/  /;x;${ x;p; }' < input
```

It works like this:

- Read each line but instead of printing it right away, save it by appending it to the hold space (`H`), except remove any newlines that separate it from whatever was already there (`x;s/^\n//;s/\n/  /;x`). (If you want tabs in your output, put them here where I've put a couple of spaces.)
- If you come across a line that matches your Accept-Language pattern, flush the hold space before you append anything to it. Print it and clear it (`x;p;s/.*//;x`). Then proceed as usual with the appending and whatnot.
- Treat the first and last lines differently from all others: never flush the hold space after reading just the first line (`1bgo` skips past that, down to the position labeled `:go`), and always flush the hold space after reading the last line (`${ x;p; }`)

Comment: This also works perfectly I should add! The only problem with it is that it takes a long time to process data on a larger scale (especially with Mapreduce). Thanks for your response